# How do i join and sum values in 3 tables where i need to group by one key column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to join 3 tables(tableA,tableB,tableC) all have 3 fields(invoice,productClass,value).tableA and tableB dont have values in productClass field and tableC does not have values in Value field. All tables have common value Invoice but different ProductClass and the result should sum values based on invoices and ProductClass

```
create table tableA (
    Invoice varchar(100),
    ProductClass varchar(100),
    Value int
)
create table tableB (
    Invoice varchar(100),
    ProductClass varchar(100),
    Value int
)
create table tableC (
    Invoice varchar(100),
    ProductClass varchar(100),
    Value int
)

insert into tableA
values
('001','',10),
('002','',20),
('003','',30),
('004','',40)


insert into tableB
values
('001','',20),
('002','',30),
('003','',40),
('004','',50)


insert into tableC
values
('001','aaa',null),
('002','aab',null),
('003','aac',null),
('004','aad',null)



select Invoice,ProductClass,sum(Value)
from(
    select * from tableA
    union
    select * from tableB
    union
    select * from tableC
)tableD
group by Invoice,ProductClass
```

i expect the results to return

```
Invoice - 001,002,003,004
ProductClass - aaa,aab,aac,aad
Value - 30,50,70,90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max()` for `ProductClass` if it has value like `blank` or `null`s:

```
select Invoice, max(ProductClass) as ProductClass, sum(Value) as Value
from(select * from tableA
     union
     select * from tableB
     union
     select * from tableC
    )tableD
group by Invoice;
```

Comment: ProductClass does not have blank or null values check tableC on the sample code that i posted

Comment: @Ronald . .  Yes `tableC` don't have a `null` or `blank` but first two table have this. So, if you are using this column in `GROUP BY` it will considered as separate group i.e (`blank`). So, for that your result would be fine. If you want single group then use `max()` in `ProductClass`.